# How can I rename a Rails controller with a route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a controller in a Rails 3 app named "my_store."  I would like to be able to use this controller as is, except replacing "my_store" in all the URL's with another name.  I do not want to rename the controller file, and all the references to it.  Is there a clean way to do this with just a routing statement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use RESTful routes:

```
resources :another_name, :controller => "my_store"
```

Otherwise:

```
match "another_name" => "my_store"
```

Answer (score 4):

If your routes are RESTful, this is pretty easy.

```
resources :photos, :controller => "images"
```

You can see how to do this and other helpful Rails routing information in the [Rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Answer (score 0):

**Update**, the other guys are correct, to replace all references you would change the resources name and corresponding controller in routes.rb!  My answer is only good to set a specific route.

Yup,  you would do this in your `routes.rb`  using the `:as` option to specify

example:

```
match 'exit' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => :logout
```

[source](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#prefixing-the-named-route-helpers)